# Execute code when form loaded and before Form closes

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I'm currently working on an application that uses a Windows Form GUI. The main work of the application will be performed on an additional thread - but it is possible that it will be dependent on the state of the form.
Because of this, before I create the thread I must make sure that the form is **completely** loaded. Also, I need to make sure the thread is terminated **before** the form begins closing.

Possible solutions for this problem might be overriding the `OnShown` and `OnFormClosing` methods. 
Does the `OnShow` method really gets called only after ALL of the assets of the form have been loaded? And what about the `OnFormClosing` - can I be sure that any code executed in this method will be performed **before** the form begins close / dispose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you read through the WinForms event ordering as posted on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx

Comment: That is an interesting read, but unfortunately it seems that even the first event (`OnClosing` / `OnFormClosing`) is fired AFTER the form has been disposed. The only thing left that I can think of is to override the close method...

Answer (score 2):

Windows Forms events can be tricky, and the order they fire unreliable. For example, the 'Shown' event is meant to fire once and once only, when the Form is first displayed, but just yesterday I found a way to completely prevent that event from firing by manipulating Form.Visible flags at the right time.

So, you need to be quite specific about your needs. For example - when you say 'completely loaded', what do you mean? Controls created, form visible, Form constructor finished executing?

Likewise, the FormClosing event might be circumvented by an unhandled exception in your main aUI thread, which results in the Form being removed without the event firing.

I suggest never assuming anything around these events. Make your worker thread capable of dealing with the Form state being unavailable, or not ready. Without knowing your exact requirements, it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: I have also encountered certain unreliability when it comes to this, but to me it seems that if I can reduce the chance of exceptions being raised beyond that level this might be enough. I do not intend to do anything beyond basic with the form itself. The only external interaction with the form will probably look like this: `form.Invoke(form.Refresh)` or `form.BeginInvoke(form.Refresh)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use InitializeComponent on the constructor of your main WinForm and use **OnLoad** (called whenever everything is loaded)?